# Cocos2d Accelerometer issue?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, accelerometer

Ive been working on a accelerometer based project using this code:

.h

```
 {
 CCSprite *donk; 

 float movement; 

 }
```

.m

```
  -(id) init
{

if( (self=[super init]) ) {


 donk = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"fe1.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
 donk.position = ccp (240,75);
 [self addChild:donk];


    [self scheduleUpdate]; 
     self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;  
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];  

}
     return self;
}


     -(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration       *)acceleration {

float deceleration = .1f; 
float sinsitivity = 10.0f; 

float acelx = +acceleration.y;
movement = movement * deceleration + acelx * sinsitivity;

 }

 - (void)update:(ccTime)delta {

CCLOG(@"Position: %f", donk.position.x);
if ( donk.position.x > 0 && donk.position.x < 480) {

donk.position = ccp(donk.position.x + movement, donk.position.y);
}

if ( donk.position.x < -55 ) {


    donk.position = ccp( 50, donk.position.y); 
}

if (donk.position.x > 430 ) {

    donk.position = ccp( 430, donk.position.y); 
}

 }
```

The really strange thing is it works in one project but i copy and pasted it into another and now it doesn't work. The sprite is on the screen but it doesn't move and the CCLOG maintains the x value of 240. Whats wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not way up on COCOS2D anymore, but shouldn't you be setting the acellerometer delegate somewhere in there? eg

```
 self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;  
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setUpdateInterval:1/60];  
[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: I tried it, it sort of worked but it just moved very slowly to the left and wouldnt go right at all, checked my code should still be something with the accelerometer

Answer (score 0):

Me also faced something similar problem in cocos2d game. Then I followed this way.

Refer answer in this question: [ACCELEROMETER IN COCOS2D](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33412/accelerometer-to-move-player-left-and-right/33427#33427)